# Add images to page.files property in backend

Tags: typo3-8.x

I'm trying to make pictures of subpages visible in my bootstrap cards. I checked the code of my bootstrap template extension which already seems to have this feature, but there's no picture visible because `page.files.0` is empty - how can I fill it with a picture in the backend (not programmatically because I want editors to do this as well)?
I tried to add files at the resources tab as seen below.
[image]
But when debugging it "Files" is empty.

```
 menu => array(5 items)
      0 => array(8 items)
         data => array(70 items)
         title => 'Kampagne01' (10 chars)
         link => '/index.php?id=5' (15 chars)
         target => NULL
         active => 0 (integer)
         current => 0 (integer)
         spacer => 0 (integer)
         files => array(empty)
```

This is the code that's trying to make the images visible in `MenuCardDir.html` from the bootstrap 4 extension:

```
<f:if condition="{page.files.0}">
    <div class="card-img-top">
        <a href="{page.link}"{f:if(condition: page.target, then: ' target="{page.target}"')} title="{page.title}" data-toggle="tooltip">
        <f:render partial="Media/Rendering/Image" arguments="{file: page.files.0, data: page.data, settings: settings, variants: variants}" />
        </a>
    </div>
</f:if>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the bootstrap template menu cards are not loading the files in the "Resources" tab. Only a thumbnail and an icon are loaded. I just overrode the "thumbnail" field with "media" which is where my images are saved. And now it works.

```
##################################################
#### Customizing for showing media field in Cards
##################################################
#Selected cards
tt_content.menu_card_list.dataProcessing.20.dataProcessing.10 {
    references.fieldName = media
}
#Cards of subpages
tt_content.menu_card_dir.dataProcessing.20.dataProcessing.10 {
    references.fieldName = media
}
```

This stuff is confusing as hell, if anyone sees through that `bootstrap_package` better and can tell me an easier way, please let me know :D